# Check If A Particular Date Is Not Overlapping Any Range In A Table

Tags: mysql, date

I am creating a hotel booking application, and I want the user to check if a particular date range is available or not, for example :

```
BookingID | StartingDate | EndDate
    1     | 01/01/2014   | 10/01/2014
    2     | 15/01/2014   | 20/01/2014
```

Suppose these are the records of my booking table. Now, the user wants to check this date range:

(Supposing there is one room in the hotel)

```
StartingDate = 11/01/2014
EndDate      = 19/01/2014
```

As you can see, this date range is not available starting from 15/01 until 20/01.

How do I check to see if a date range is not overlapping with any date ranges in the existing records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple query:

```
SELECT COUNT(BookingID) 
FROM foo f 
WHERE f.StartingDate < to_date('19/01/2014') AND f.EndDate > to_date('11/01/2014');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this logic:

```
select count(*) as NumOverlappingRecords
from booking b
where @StartingDate <= b.EndDate and
      @EndDate >= b.startingDate;
```

You want `NumOverlappingRecords` to be `0` for no conflicts.